# How to multiply a vector and a square matrix with Kronecker product, and know the answer's shape?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, kronecker-product, kronecker-symbol

- $\mathbf{1}_n \in \mathbb{I}^{n\times 1}$ is a vector of ones with shape $n\times 1$
- $\mathbf{I}_m \in \mathbb{I}^{m\times m}$ is an identity matrix with shape $m\times m$

What is the answer to, and shape of, $\mathbf{1}_n^\top \otimes  \mathbf{I}_m$ ?

$$\mathbf{1}_n^\top \otimes  \mathbf{I}_m  = \overset{(1\times n)}{\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \dots 1
\end{pmatrix}}
\otimes
\overset{(m\times m)}{\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots &\vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1
\end{pmatrix}}
=?
$$

Comment: Your question is stated as an isolated problem without any context and lacks any effort of your own. It is likely to attract down votes and get closed. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and improve your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $$\underbrace{[I_m|I_m|\cdots|I_m]}_{n \ \text{times}}$$

because is $A$ is $p \times q$ and $B$ is $m \times m$:

$$A\otimes B=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}B&\cdots&a_{1q}B\\ \vdots&&\vdots\\
a_{p1}B&\cdots&a_{pq}B\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

Therefore the shape of $\mathbf{1}_n^\top \otimes  \mathbf{I}_m$ is $m \times mn$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115758/discussion-on-answer-by-jean-marie-how-to-multiply-a-vector-and-a-square-matrix).